# Is there a linux pdf viewer that can display thumbnails of a long document?

Tags: linux, pdf, viewer

I would like to see my whole document at once, so it would be nice to have a viewer that can fill the screen with thumbnails. Is there any viewer for linux (or other) that can do that? I have tried a few with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gnome's excellent default PDF viewer, [Evince](http://projects.gnome.org/evince/), does this. Just drag the side pane so that it fills the whole screen. It's very lightweight, too.

[image]

Evince's website links to a similar application for KDE called [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) (I haven't used it, but you might want to try it if you prefer Qt).

[image]